# List downloaded files in Android using Spinner

Tags: android, csv, download, spinner

My app involves downloading a few csv files and then choosing one of them to perform some functions. After the user downloads the required files, a spinner must display the files that have been downloaded. On selecting the required file, it must link to another activity where the path of the file chosen is the FileName. Is this possible using a spinner and how do I go about it?

```
    File selected = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/");

    String item_ext = "";
    try {
        item_ext = selected.getName().substring(selected.getName().lastIndexOf("."));

    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        item_ext = "";
    }

    if(item_ext.equalsIgnoreCase(".csv")) {
        Intent txtIntent = new Intent();
        txtIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        txtIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(selected), "text/csv");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try {
            startActivity(txtIntent);
        } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            txtIntent.setType("text/*");
            startActivity(txtIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, You've used too many requirements like **This should** and **That must**, Can we see your effort first ?

Comment: Why don't you try to do it first and then post if you are getting some error?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I am aware of how to create a spinner and the path to downloaded files is "/storage/emulated/0/Download/". At present, I am reading a downloaded csv file as follows:                                            `String FileName = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/MyDocument_17_May.csv";
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(FileName));` Please help.

Comment: post the relevant codes and where you were stocked.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Edit: The code is as shown above. I am searching for csv files in Internal Storage. The toast is not displayed in this case. However, only when a single file is hardcoded, the toast is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my application requirement mainly dealt with downloaded files, I linked the app to Downloads folder. By clicking on the file of interest, the path for the file was obtained. This [link](http://www.limbaniandroid.com/2014/03/how-to-get-absolute-path-when-select.html) helped to get the absolute path and was suitably modified for the purpose.